# I am am getting a Syntax Error while I compile my function In Access Vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two functions that I wrote, they both work up until the point when I try adding additional arguments. This first function works and does not have the error. I wrote this so I could easily get the values of my controls based off the actual control name.

```
    Public Function GetControlValue(name As String, FormName As Form) As Object

        Dim obj As Object

        For Each obj In FormName.Controls
            If obj.name = name Then
                Set GetControlValue = obj
             Exit Function
            End If

        Next

    End Function
```

The name variable is the name of the actual form control, and FormName is the name of the form that the control is on.

This next function is where the error occurs, I left the Remaining part of the function off just to save space, let me know if you need the rest of it.

```
Public Function SqFtGalCovAfterUpdate(RowNumber As Integer, frmName as String)

     Dim SqFtGalCov As Object
     Dim TranEff    As Object
     Dim NetSqFtGal As Object

     Set SqFtGalCov = GetControlValue("tb" & RowNumber,frmName)
     Set TranEff = GetControlValue("tb" & RowNumber + 1,frmName)
     Set NetSqFtGal = GetControlValue("tb" & RowNumber + 2,frmName)
```

If I try to pass the name of the form through the variable frmName as the FormName argument in GetControlValue function then I get a syntax error. Now if I cut out the frmName argument from the SqFtGalCovAfterUpdate function, and type the form name directly and not by variable it will work.

```
Public Function SqFtGalCovAfterUpdate(RowNumber As Integer)


 Dim SqFtGalCov As Object
 Dim TranEff    As Object
 Dim NetSqFtGal As Object

 Set SqFtGalCov = GetControlValue("tb" & RowNumber,NO VARIABLE JUST TYPE IT IN)
 Set TranEff = GetControlValue("tb" & RowNumber + 1,frmName)
 Set NetSqFtGal = GetControlValue("tb" & RowNumber + 2,frmName)
```

It works when I just type the form name directly, so I am assuming I am not declaring my frmName argument correctly in the SqFtGalCovAfterUpdate function.

```
Public Function SqFtGalCovAfterUpdate(RowNumber As Integer, frmName As Form)

 Dim SqFtGalCov As Object
 Dim TranEff    As Object
 Dim NetSqFtGal As Object

 Set SqFtGalCov = GetControlValue("tb" & RowNumber, frmName)
 Set TranEff = GetControlValue("tb" & RowNumber + 1, frmName)
 Set NetSqFtGal = GetControlValue("tb" & RowNumber + 2, frmName)
```

I changed frmName As from

I dim the objects as controls and frmName as string but get the same reslults

```
Public Function SqFtGalCovAfterUpdate(RowNumber As Integer, frmName As String)

 Dim SqFtGalCov As Control
 Dim TranEff    As Control
 Dim NetSqFtGal As Control

 Set SqFtGalCov = GetControlValue("tb" & RowNumber, Forms(frmName))
 Set TranEff = GetControlValue("tb" & RowNumber + 1, Forms(frmName))
 Set NetSqFtGal = GetControlValue("tb" & RowNumber + 2, Forms(frmName))

Public Function GetControlValue(name As String, FormName As Form) As Control

    Dim obj As Control
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still pass a string, thus you need to assign the form by its name:

```
Public Function SqFtGalCovAfterUpdate(RowNumber As Integer, frmName as String)

     Dim SqFtGalCov As Object
     Dim TranEff    As Object
     Dim NetSqFtGal As Object

     Set SqFtGalCov = GetControlValue("tb" & RowNumber, Forms(frmName))
     Set TranEff = GetControlValue("tb" & RowNumber + 1, Forms(frmName))
     Set NetSqFtGal = GetControlValue("tb" & RowNumber + 2, Forms(frmName))
```

Also, as the objects are controls, dim them as such and return a control:

```
Public Function GetControlValue(name As String, FormName As Form) As Control

    Dim obj As Control
```

and:

```
    Dim SqFtGalCov As Control
    Dim TranEff    As Control
    Dim NetSqFtGal As Control
```

**Edit:**

Then try to pass the form name all the way:

```
Public Function GetControlValue(name As String, FormName As String) As Control

    Dim obj As Control

    For Each obj In Forms(FormName).Controls
        If obj.name = name Then
            Set GetControlValue = obj
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: I accidentally hit the accept button, I am still getting the same error

Comment: OK. Perhaps you just need to pass the form name. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

In GetControlValue you declare FormName as Form, in SqFtGalCovAfterUpdate frmName is a String.

Comment: And this is why good naming matters. "form name" is screaming "I'm a string", not "I'm a form object reference".

Comment: I still get the error even when I change frmName to form object

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly for us to see.